# Problem with keeping prevoius app when deploying from visual studio

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, prism

When I deploy an app, I created with the Blank Prism template for Xamarin, to Android my other app created with the same template is removed from the device. How do one configure Prism to avoid this?

Comment: change the app id

Comment: it actually was the package name that had to be changed, had no idea that prism set it to the same value for all projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [document:Set the application ID](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html):

> Every Android app has **a unique application ID** that looks like a Java
> package name, such as com.example.myapp. This ID uniquely identifies
> your app on the device and in Google Play Store. If you want to upload
> a new version of your app, the application ID (and the certificate you
> sign it with) must be the **same** as the original APK—**if you change the
> application ID, Google Play Store treats the APK as a completely
> different app**. So once you publish your app, you should never change
> the application ID.

You should probably change your app's application ID to make it as a new app.
Your project's package name matches the application ID by default.

For more information about change the package name, see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html#change_the_package_name).